# CRM 2011 write value in form field without updating database

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I'm developing a plugin for dynamics crm 2011. I have to write the calculated value only temporarily in a field on the form without saving it in the database. Is that possible? And if it is how can I do it?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be a small web resource on the form to display your custom value. Using the XRM property you can access the data on the form "live" i.e. before it is saved to the database.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Fortunately I have solved It before I saw your answer. I have done a Retrieve Plugin and then I changed the OutputParameter. Thank You anyway